# Right Click Menu on Tkinter Treeview widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am trying to make a popup menu appear, unique to each row, appear when right clicking on a specific row in a Treeview table with TTK.

I found some code [here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-popup-menu.htm) which does what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if it's possible for the code to discern between right clicks on one row or another. 
Below is my full code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys

class Main:
    def __init__(self, root):
        pass

    def treeview_sort_column(self, tv, col, reverse):
        l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
        try:
            l.sort(key=lambda t: int(t[0]), reverse=reverse)

        except ValueError:
            l.sort(reverse=reverse)

        for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
            tv.move(k, '', index)
        tv.heading(col, command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))

    def createWindow(self):
        self.popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
        self.popup.add_command(label="Shutdown") # , command=next) etc...
        self.popup.add_command(label="Edit Name")
        self.popup.add_separator()
        self.popup.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: self.closeWindow())

        Button(root, text="Exit", command=lambda: self.closeWindow()).pack()

        self.columns = ('Name', 'Age', 'Height')
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=self.columns, show='headings')
        self.treeview.pack()
        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', values=("Josh", "18", "198"))
        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', values=("LJ", "36", "167"))
        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', values=("Klaudia", "12", "200"))
        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', values=("David", "74", "134"))

        self.treeview.bind("<Button-3>", self.do_popup)

        for col in self.columns:
            self.treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                             self.treeview_sort_column(self.treeview, _col, False))

    def closeWindow(self):
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit()

    def do_popup(self, event):
        try:
            self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
        finally:
            self.popup.grab_release()

root = Tk()
X = Main(root)
X.createWindow()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Apologies, I have added the correct code now. To clarify, pop up menus are created with this code, but I want the code to be able to tell if it clicks on Row 1 or Row 30 e.g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `identify_row()` method of the treeview:

```
def do_popup(self, event):
    item = self.treeview.identify_row(event.y)
    print('clicked item:', item)
    try:
        self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
    finally:
        self.popup.grab_release()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much