# Apply drop down selection to tree view row

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a function that will apply a drop-down box selection to a treeview row. Ideally by clicking on the desired row in the GUI, then selecting a value from the drop down selection `StatusList`. Then I would like to input the chosen drop down selection into the row that was clicked. The column to enter the drop-down selection in would be `Current Status`

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    # row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)
    for row in reader:
        RoNumber = row['Ro Number']
        DateIn = row['Date In']
        RegoNumber = row['Rego Number']
        CustomerName = row['Customer Name']
        VehicleDetails = row['Vehicle Details']
        JobDescription = row['Job Description']
        CurrentStatus = row['Current Status']
        treetime.insert("", 0, values=(RoNumber, DateIn, RegoNumber, CustomerName, VehicleDetails, JobDescription, CurrentStatus))

    ##Counts the number of rows in CSV file 
# with open(filepath) as f:
#     reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
#     row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)

StatusList = [
    "Carry Over",
    "Waiting On Parts",
    "Waiting On Car Wash",
    "Yet to Arrive",
    "Not Started",
    "Being Worked On"
]

Status = StringVar()
Status.set(0)

drop = OptionMenu(root, Status, *StatusList)
drop.place(x=1253,y=80, height=25, width=150)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `command` option of the `OptionMenu` to insert the chosen value in the treeview. It takes a function with one argument, which is the selected value, and this function is triggered each time the user selects a value in the `OptionMenu`. In this function, you need to get the currently selected row, which can be done with `treetime.focus()`, then change the value in the 'CurrentStatus' column, with `treetime.set(<selected row>, 'CurrentStatus', <new status>)`:

```
def set_status(value):
    row = treetime.focus()  # get selected row
    if row:
        treetime.set(row, 'CurrentStatus', value)  # change value in CurrentStatus column
```

I have assumed here that you have created your columns like:

```
treetime = ttk.Treeview(..., columns=(..., 'CurrentStatus', ...))
```

and that 'CurrentStatus' is the one you want to edit.

Additionally, it would be nice that the initially selected value in the `OptionMenu` corresponds to the one of the currently selected row. For that you can use a binding to the `<<TreeviewSelect>>` event which is triggered every time the selection changes. You can get the value in a given cell with `treetime.set(<row>, <column>)`, so the bound function is

```
def tree_select(event):
    row = treetime.focus()  # get selected row
    if row:
        Status.set(treetime.set(row, 'CurrentStatus'))
```

Here is a full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
treetime = ttk.Treeview(root, show='headings', columns=('Row', 'CurrentStatus'))
treetime.pack()
treetime.heading('Row', text='Row')
treetime.heading('CurrentStatus', text='Current Status')

for i in range(10):
    tree.insert("", "end", values=(i, "Not Started"))


statusList = [
    "Carry Over",
    "Waiting On Parts",
    "Waiting On Car Wash",
    "Yet to Arrive",
    "Not Started",
    "Being Worked On"
]

status = tk.StringVar()
status.set("Not Started")


def tree_select(event):
    row = treetime.focus()
    if row:
        status.set(treetime.set(row, 'CurrentStatus'))

treetime.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', tree_select)

def set_status(value):
    row = treetime.focus()
    if row:
        treetime.set(row, 'CurrentStatus', value)


drop = ttk.OptionMenu(root, status, "Not Started", *statusList, command=set_status)
drop.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, my columns are inserted as below.. looks like the code will need to be manipulated to suit? `treetime.column("Column2", width=100, minwidth=50)`

Comment: and renamed using  `treetime.heading('Column10', text="Current Status", anchor=tk.W)`

Comment: @JamesCook if the column you want to edit is named 'Column10', then replace 'CurrentStatus' by 'Column10' everywhere in my answer. Also, the point of my full example is just to be able to quickly see that my solution works without needing all the csv data and to show you how I used the binding and options. What you really need is to insert the code of the functions `set_status()` and `tree_select()` in your code and connect them to your widgets.

Comment: @j_4321 Is there a way to have the drop-down menu on the wanted cell, instead of the OptionMenu? Namely, all configurable cells will have their own drop-down menus to select from.

Comment: @ThanasisMattas Yes it is possible but this is a different question. You can start by looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062557/right-click-menu-on-tkinter-treeview-widget, and if you get stuck, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately, it is not exactly what I want. Using the current example, I would like statusList to be embedded to all cells under CurrentStatus column (if the parent value is not '') and be able to choose a value from a drop-down menu.

Comment: @ThanasisMattas Then please ask a new question in which you can link to this question if needed.